# qsort on array of void*

Tags: c, qsort

So, I have a function to compare two const void* pointers, one pointer is bigger then other if it has bigger address

```
int func (const void* a, const void* b)
{
     return (int)((long)(a) - (long)(b));
}
```

I have an array of void* and array[0] is bigger than array[1]

```
void* array[2];
void* a = malloc(10);
void* b = malloc(10);
if (func(a, b) < 0)
{
    array[0] = b;
    array[1] = a;
}
else
{
    array[0] = a;
    array[1] = b;
}
// for example, array contains 0x15cfeb0 and 0x15cfe90
```

And after that I'm doing qsort and the array doesn't change!

```
qsort(array, 2, sizeof(void*), (*func));
// array is 0x15cfeb0 and 0x15cfe90 instead of expected 0x15cfe90 and 0x15cfeb0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `(*func)` notation in the call to `qsort()` is kinda eccentric; it would be sufficient — and conventional — to use just `func`, though some might suggest `&func` (but the `&` is pointless, if harmless), just as the `*` is pointless and more or less harmless.  The parentheses are just superfluous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments to the comparison function are pointers to the array elements, not the array elements themselves. So you need to compare what they point to.

```
int func (const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return (int)((long)(*(void **)a) - (long)(*(void **)b));
}
```

BTW, what you're doing is not really well defined. The result of converting a pointer to an integer is implementation-dependent.

There can also be overflow when converting the result of subtracting `long` to `int`. It would be better to just test them for less than or greater than:

```
uintptr_t aval = (uintptr_t)(*(void **)a);
uintptr_t bval = (uintptr_t)(*(void **)b);
if (aval == bval) {
    return 0;
} else if (aval < bval) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If speed is an issue, test for less than and greater than first and second, rather than testing for equality first.  Most trivial comment of the day. :-)

Comment: @M.M Good suggestion

Comment: Or simply use a cast to `char` for the pointer size, e.g. `return *((char * const *)a) - *((char * const *)b);` (this does impose a limit of `INT_MAX` between any two pointers)